What is the maximum length of AWS MSK Cluster Policy?
I'm standing up a Kafka cluster using AWS MSK. I'm using cross account access so have defined Cluster Policy (Resource) and Identity policy.  I'm going to have statements in the Cluster Policy for every principal that will be producing and consuming.  I haven't found any docs on the upper limit of this Cluster Policy.  I've tried to find it by just adding more and more statements to the policy.  I'm up to 14k and haven't hit an upper boundary.  Does anybody happen to know what the upper boundary might be?

I heard from AWS support about this.

I would like to inform you that, we have a size limit on the MSK cluster policy and the max size/character limit is 20k.

